# Is it safe to truncate the schema_migrations table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-migration

**TL;DR**

If I miss some migration files and I want to recreate the database, is it ok to dump the schema/structure and delete all rows of the `schema_migrations` table, so that I don't get a pending migrations error?

**Long version**

Some terminology I'll use:

- *default database* - the database that Rails expects/creates by default, it has a name of the form **appname_development** / **appname_test** etc, depending on the environment.
- *main database* - in a multi-db environment - the database, where most, but not all models are stored. All the models of this databse have `establish_connection` lines in their declarations.

Warning: I'll describe an app with many violations of Rails best practices, for most of which I don't know the reason. My goal is to get things back on track.

I recently took over the development of an app, which was using several databases. The main database (which was not ***appname_development***) was manipulated in the following way - there was a separate Rails app solely for the purpose of manipulating the db through migrations. So, for example, if you wanted to add a model, you go to the other app, create the migration, run it, and in the main app you only create the model file with the code. In the main app there were some migrations, because there were also a few models stored in the default database (**appname_development**). On top of that some of the developers had altered the databases directly via `psql`.

I wanted to make the main database the default database, so I changed `database.yml`, so that `development` was pointing to the main database and I removed the `establish_connection` lines from the models. Also, I moved to using `structure.sql`, instead of `schema.rb`, because the database has a lot of stored procedures.

The problem I encounter, however, is that the `schema_migrations` table contains many rows, for which I don't have respective migrations and the app reports that there are `pending migrations`. I have a lot of entries, for which I don't have a corresponding file:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20131007211329  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211336  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211343  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211349  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211355  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211402  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211409  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211415  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211422  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211428  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131007211436  ********** NO FILE **********
```

Now, my question is - is it ok, if I just delete these rows and "start clean". Also, if I run `rails g migration`, will a normal migration be generated and will a corresponding row in the `schema_migrations` table be created?

A few final thoughts - for me, currently it is not an option to simply recreate the db via `rake db:reset`, because there are approximately 5GB worth of data. I now that normally one should use a `seeds.rb` file, but right now I don't have time to dive into the details of the project and generate the seed data, but must work with the production data. My idea is the following:

- truncate the `schema_migrations` table, so that I don't have pending migrations error;
- export **only the data** from the main database;
- drop the database;
- `rake db:create`
- `rake db:structure:load` so that I have the db structure, custom types and stored procedures;
- import the data dump into the new database;
- make any future changes to the db via normal Rails migrations, so that I drop down to `psql` as seldom as possible;

Thank you in advance for the information and I am willing to provide any additional info.

Comment: Well if in your migrations you have code only related to schema then its fine, just taking a schema dump would be enough. But if you migrations had data migration, where you wanted to load some default values to those tables. Then you have problem. They will be lost.

Comment: Delete the migration_id and next time you wont get any migration error..else edit timestamp of migration file and rerun...only if you dont have the table present